# Which relationship between mood and frequency spectrum is known?

Tags: c#, mono, signal-processing, fft

I applied a FFT to an audio file, showing the frequencies spread while playing the audio file.

Is there a scientific approach to finding moods like euphoric/sad/melancholic based on frequency distribution snapshots or series of snapshots?

My idea:

The number of maxima above a certain threshold of circa 20% of the highest peak is greater or less than a certain value results in euphoric or not. The theory is that euphoric music parts are often accompanied by a lot of chords/different instruments so when a lot of different frequencies are being played at the same time, it is likely to be euphoric.

A lot of false positives though.

Comment: You could use machine learning/NeuralNets for the program, but as fat as i know each music type has specific patterns that you could use to identify what type is them.

Comment: @AsshO.Le Please elaborate. Also it is about determining different parts *within one* song.

Comment: what do you mean by `different parts within one song`

Comment: @AsshO.Le I don't want to detect a song's 'global' mood but I want to find out areas that are meant to be euphoric and those that are in between/lead up to a new euphoric part in the same song. This in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of looking at how strong the peaks are vs the background will tell you how "noisy" vs "pitched" the music is, which might tell you how instrumental vs percussive it is, although the technique could misinterpret percussive for other kinds of noise, like ambient/environmental noises and sound effects. I don't think that wins you much.

From the FFT, you can also derive other parameters like spectral centroid, which correlates closely with our perception of brightness, and so on.

However, the FFT alone does not begin to capture what we might call the "mood" or "emotional content" of music. Some examples of information not captured:

- **The key of the music.** Just because a song is in a minor key does not make it "sad", but it plays a major role in the mood of the song.
- **The tempo.** The tempo of the song is a major indicator of emotional content.

Comment: Also, depending on the relationship between the peaks, the sound could be either very harsh and dissonant or very consonant and pleasant.

Answer (score 0):

You could research more in Google, but it's not the frequency only that tells the mood of a music, there are lots of [factor](http://music.columbia.edu/cmc/musicandcomputers/chapter1/01_03.php)
Depending on the said factors you can set the specific mood of a music,
Example: Beats are very slow but frequenct/notes are very high, it might emphasize a very deep sadness.

You could look in the internet for different [moods](http://www.allmusic.com/moods) of music, after that determine their tempo,frequency,note,timbre, their patterns will match a specific kind of music. you could use neural nets to familiarize your system in determining the mood of a sound based on the patterns you have researched..